# Running code shows 'this.props.dispatch is not a function' after adding mapDispatchToProps

Tags: redux

Let me tell you, this code were working fine and showing all products in shop page **but** after adding **mapDispatchToProps**.
it giving error:- TypeError: this.props.getProducts is not a function

mapStateToProps is giving products.
Trying to post data using mapDispatchToProps.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts } from '../actions/productsAction';
import { addToCart } from '../actions/cartAction';

class Shop extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pid: '',
      pname: '',
      pprice: '',
      pimg: '',
      qty: '',
      total_price: '',
      getValue:[]
    };
  }   

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getProducts());
    
    let getValue = localStorage.getItem("userData");     
    this.setState({ 
      getValue: JSON.parse(getValue), 
    });   
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pid = this.state.pid;
    const pname = this.state.pname;
    const pprice = this.state.pprice;
    const pimg = this.state.pimg;
    const qty = this.state.qty;
    const total_price = this.state.total_price;
    const email = this.state.getValue.email;
    const CartData = {pid: pid, pname: pname, pprice: pprice, pimg: pimg, qty:qty, total_price:total_price}
    this.props.addToCart(CartData);
  };

  render() {
      return (
      ...html code
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="pid" value={product._id} />  
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="pname" value={product.pname} />  
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="pprice" value={product.pprice} />  
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="qty" value="1" />  
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="pimage" value={product.pimg} />
        <input type="hidden" onChange={this.handleChange} name="total_price" value={product.pprice} />
        <button type="submit" class="pro-btn"><i class="icon-basket"></i></button>
     </form>
     ...html code

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ products: state.products });

const mapDispatchToProps = { addToCart };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Shop);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the `mapDispatchToProps` properly.

It should look like below,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => { 
    return { 
        addToCart: () => dispatch(addToCart()),
        getProducts: () => dispatch(getProducts())
    }
};
```

And you should call the function directly using props

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProducts();
    
    let getValue = localStorage.getItem("userData");     
    this.setState({ 
      getValue: JSON.parse(getValue), 
    });   
  }
```

Comment: They are using the [object shorthand notation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object).

Comment: @LindaPaiste, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera thank you for the answer, its working now.

Comment: @Abhi, great! please make it as the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two actions that you want to use in your component, so you'll want to include them both in your `mapDispatchToProps` object.  The function notation described by @AmilaSenadheera will work, but the [object shorthand](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) is easier.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addToCart,
  getProducts
};
```

Then you should be able to call `this.props.getProducts()`.